# Most optimized way to search for an Object in an ArrayList

Tags: powershell, performance, optimization

I have a list of IPs (list "X") for which I'm trying to find the domain name.
I also have an Excel file containing 170 000+ entries of IP with the corresponding domain name.

So first I import the Excel file:
`$dnsEntries = Import-Excel -Path '.\file.xlsx' -WorksheetName "list"`

And then for each IP in list "X", I try to find it in `$dnsEntries`, so I can get the domain name:

```
foreach($IP in $IPs) {
    $DN=($dnsEntries.Where({$_."Address" -like $IP})).Name
}
```

Unfortunately, this takes at least 2 seconds for each IP, and I have 5000+, so this takes a loong time. What bothers me is that Excel can find ALL 5000+ corresponding domain names in less than 3 seconds with a simple formula. I understand that I could never come this close with PowerShell, but how the difference could be so big?

Is there any way I could speed up the search?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: Here is a reproducible example. Some IPs won't be matched.

```
$IPs = @("10.10.10.1","10.10.10.5","10.10.10.66","10.10.10.99","10.10.10.235","10.10.10.73","10.10.10.98","10.10.10.56")
$dnsEntries = @(
    @{Address="10.10.10.73";Name="ip1.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.98";Name="ip2.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.1";Name="ip3.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.56";Name="ip4.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.235";Name="ip5.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.5";Name="ip6.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.11";Name="ip7.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.81";Name="ip8.local"},
    @{Address="10.10.10.2";Name="ip9.local"}
)

foreach($IP in $IPs) {
    $DN=($dnsEntries.Where({$_."Address" -like $IP})).Name
    Write-Host $DN
}
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. Some _sanitized_ excerpts from `$IPs` and `$dnsEntries`…

Comment: Definitely can speed it up, `$dnsEntries` should be a hash table. Are the IPs on the `Address` column of your excel file unique?

Comment: How do you initialise the $IPs variable? If it’s a reference to an COM object it’ll be way faster to read all the values into an in-memory array rather than iterate over the Excel cell objects every time.

Comment: Also, ```-eq``` will probably be faster than ```-like``` if your data is in a format that works with that instead. (Or pre-process your sata so it *does* work woth ```-eq```.

Comment: I think you mean `$DN`.

Comment: - I edited my post to add a reproducible example and correct my code.
- Hashtables are faster to go through ? The IPs are unique.
- $IPs is in memory as as an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in one of the comments, I converted the `$dnsEntries` from an ArrayList to a Hashtable with the following code:

```
$import = Import-Excel -Path '.\file.xlsx' -WorksheetName "list"
$dnsEntries = @{}

foreach($entry in $import){
    $dnsEntries.Add($entry.Address,$entry.Name)
}

foreach($IP in $IPs) {
    $DN=$dnsEntries[$IP]
    Write-Host $DN
}
```

It still takes a long time to convert it, but then looking for a domain name for an IP is almost instant! So in the end it saves a lot of time.

Thanks to all of you for your advice!